# Kafka offsetcommit request with high level consumer API

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I would like to use Kafka high level consumer API, and at the same time I would like to disable auto commit of offsets. I tried to achieve this through the following steps.

```
1) auto.commit.enable = false
2) offsets.storage = kafka
3) dual.commit.enabled = false
```

I created a offset manager, which periodically creates offsetcommit request to kafka and commits the offset.

Still I have the following questions

1) Does high level consumer API automatically fetches offset from kafka storage and initializes itself with that offset? Or should I use simple consumer API to achieve this?

2) Does kafka based storage for offsets is repicated across all brokers? Or it is maintained on only one broker?

Answer (score 0):

> I created a offset manager, which periodically creates offsetcommit request to kafka and commits the offset.

You need not do that if you are using the high level consumer which provides you with methods to commit the offsets manually, the [javadoc](https://kafka.apache.org/0101/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) (under Manual Offset Control) provides you with examples on how to do that.

> 1) Does high level consumer API automatically fetches offset from kafka storage and initializes itself with that offset? Or should I use simple consumer API to achieve this?

High level consumer will take care of fetching the last committed offset when you restart it, so you can resume consuming from where you left off.

> 2) Does kafka based storage for offsets is repicated across all brokers? Or it is maintained on only one broker?

Kafka stores the consumer offsets in an internal topic named `__consumer_offsets` and by default its replication factor is set to 3 with 50 partitions. So it is replicated across 3 brokers. You can find more info on its configuration in [broker config](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation#brokerconfigs), they start with `offset` or `offsets`.